# Condensed milk instead of evaporated

Tags: substitutions

I'm making pumpkin custard and it calls for 1 can evaporated milk AND 3/4 c.sugar. I have a can of condensed milk. Can I used the condensed milk instead? Add a little milk or water?

Answer (score 2):

I did this just a few days ago.  The result was really quite good and I will never go back to evaporated milk.  I added no extra sugar and the result was less sweet than normal.  The texture was a bit fluffier too.